# Change Marker position + Replace close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Please check this screenshot to understand completely the problem:
[image: problems]

**My first question is**:
How could I move the `InfoWindow` lower near the pin itself? I tried with css, javascript, etc and I cannot seem to find a "non hacky" way of doing it.

**My second question is**:
Is there any way to close an `InfoWindow` from my custom `InfoWindow`? I know I can do infoWindow.close() but I don't think I have the `InfoWindow` instance from a `jquery` event (it's a normal `InfoWindow` but with custom html in it).

Any help will be greatly welcome :)

Thanks and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

From the [API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow)  on `pixelOffset`:

> The offset, in pixels, of the tip of the info window from the point on the map at whose geographical coordinates the info window is anchored

For the second question, you don't want to use jQuery events to open the infowindow, instead you can use  the `content` property of the options to set your custom html, then do something like this:

```
var myInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: 'customHTML',
                                                //some mode options
                                              })

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (event) {
    if (myInfoWindow) {
         myInfoWindow.close()
         myInfoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
         myInfoWindow.open(map, marker);
    }

 })
```